# Headers are not aligning with body table when I set scroll only for body. Also scroll is set for the body yet it's disabled

Tags: html, css, header, overflow, html-table

Headers are not aligning with body table when I set scroll only for body. Also scroll is set for the body yet it's disabled.

Here is the html code:

```
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="mwp_Row1">
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
                <input type="button" name="Close" value="Close" onclick="javascript:window.close()" class="button">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <div style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

            <tr class="mwp_titleBand">          
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Service Date</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">New/Old Data</td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Accom Code</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Room Code</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Rate Code</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Block Inv Count</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Block Alot Count</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Book Count</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Hold Count</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">BlockInv Wash Factor</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Bk Blk Impact Count</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">PrntBrw Impact Count</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">System Created</div></td>
                <td class=rotate align="center"><div align="center">Modification Type</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">



                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td align="center">04-AUG-16</td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>New Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center">CQ</td>
                            <td align="center">GRP</td>
                            <td align="center">2</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td align="center">05-AUG-16</td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>New Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center">CQ</td>
                            <td align="center">GRP</td>
                            <td align="center">2</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td align="center">06-AUG-16</td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>New Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center">CQ</td>
                            <td align="center">GRP</td>
                            <td align="center">2</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td align="center">07-AUG-16</td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>New Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center">CQ</td>
                            <td align="center">GRP</td>
                            <td align="center">2</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td align="center">08-AUG-16</td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>New Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center">CQ</td>
                            <td align="center">GRP</td>
                            <td align="center">2</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center">0</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                            <td></td>
                            <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                            <td align="center">1C</td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                            <td align="center"></td>
                        </tr>



    </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Also below is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2zo7msg/4/

I want the headers to be fixed ...and the body to have scrollbar Also I want the headers table to in alignment with the body table (If you see now it is not). Also scroll bar is not working on the body.

Comment: What does you want exactly?? please elaborate more!!!

Comment: 1.I want the headers to be fixed ...and the body to have scrollbar Also i want the headers table to in alignment with the body table(If u see now it is not). Also scroll bar is not working on the body

Comment: Hi please use http://jsfiddle.net/k2zo7msg/4/ for ur reference ..i need to align this and also fix the scrollbar

Comment: Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/cwvezsr8/1/

Comment: Hi Sunil...It works really really well on mozilla but on IE i get both horizontal and vertical scroll.....:( If u run ur same fiddle on IE it will show u what i mean

Comment: Which version are you using of IE ??

Comment: IE8 not support CSS 3 property's, IE9 not supporting rotate property for more info you can check screenshots here : https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/ac96d4d16fe2dcb9577d8c11b7c8e429b9242dec

Comment: Yes i removed .scrolltable{overflow:auto} and it worked perfectly on IE 11 !!!!

Comment: hey one issue is still there....can u help out ...in the body columns the white divider is gone ...like if u see the header there is a white divider between the columns...i need same for body...pls help out

Comment: Check my updated fiddle in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `position: absolute` and `position: relative` for the alignment:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2zo7msg/3/

Comment: can u elaborate how i can use position fixed/absolute in this example http://jsfiddle.net/k2zo7msg/4/

Comment: I thought it is just one line.. well, in that case all you can do is either to give them a width so they are the same, which is not really a good solution or to put them inside the same div so the line up like you want them to..

Answer (score 0):

I have used `-webkit-flex` and `table:fixed` property to fix header... check below code for more detail or you also

Check [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwvezsr8/3/)

**CSS**

```
#constrainer {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.scrolltable {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.scrolltable > .body {
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    width:100%;
}
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight:normal;
}
th.rotate > div {
    transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(2px, 41px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(270deg);
    width: 30px;
    margin-left:-12px;
}
.mwp_titleBand {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ccccff;
}
.mwp_Row1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 21px;
}
th + th {
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="constrainer">
    <div class="scrolltable">
        <table class="header" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="98%">
            <thead>
                <tr class="mwp_titleBand">
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Service Date</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >New/Old Data</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Accom Code</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Room Code</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Rate Code</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Block Inv Count</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Block Alot Count</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Book Count</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Hold Count</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >BlockInv Wash Factor</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Bk Blk Impact Count</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >PrntBrw Impact Count</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >System Created</div></th>
                    <th class="rotate" align="center"><div >Modification Type</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div class="body">
            <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="mwp_Row1" align="center">
                        <td align="center">Date</td>
                        <td align="center"><strong>Old Data</strong></td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                        <td align="center">Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```